# Writing data to text file in windows 8

Tags: json, html, windows-8

I'm developing a Windows 8 application using HTML5. The application requires some user data to create a new event. The event has a title, description, date and time. I want to store this data in a text file in JSON format after the user has filled the form so that it can be visible the next time user opens the application.

I can find different methods of writing JSON objects to text file but I can't find anything related to appending data at the end of the text file. Basically, I have one events.txt from which I read and display data and I want to append events to the same .txt after user adds an event.

My events.txt looks like this

```
[
        {
        "key": "event1",
        "title": "title1", 
        "description": "description1",
        "date": "<sample date>",
        "time": "<sample time>",
        "backgroundImage": "../images/logo.png"
        }
]
```

I'm reading the events from this file using the following code

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: "../data/events.txt" }).then(function (xhr) {
        var events = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        events.forEach(function (feed) {
            event.push({
                group: feed,
                key: feed.key,
                title: feed.title,
                description: feed.description,
                date: feed.date,
                time: feed.time,
                backgroundImage: feed.backgroundImage
            });
        });
    });
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated as I'm running tight on a deadline here.

Thanks.

Comment: If you think this is not the best way to do what I'm doing, then please let me know how to proceed. Like I said, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this [File Access sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597) for `Consumer Preview`?

If I understood your question correctly, I think here are some important API that you want to use.

```
// Create a file
var eventFile;
Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.createFileAsync("event.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists).done(function (file) {
        eventFile = file;
    });

// Write Text to a file
Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(eventFile, JSON.stringify(yourJSONObject));

// Append Text to a file
Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync(eventFile, JSON.stringify(yourJSONObject));
```

More reference to FileIO API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701440.aspx

In addition, why don't you consider using `local storage` or `indexedDB` to store your event info?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had gone through the File Access sample. From what I understand, the file is created everytime the application is opened, right? I'm just trying out the API again. I want the updated data to be available everytime the user opens the app.

Comment: @user870681 From my own experience, the data is persistent. As long as you don't remove it, it should be there. You can use `Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists` to avoid overwriting the file.

Comment: I have been trying this since then, but the application kept crashing. I then tried 'Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.local.createFileAsync("events.txt");'
I am able to write the data in the file using this but now I have problems reading it. any ideas? Do you want me to post the full code?

Comment: I guess you would probably wanna fix the Crash first, cuz it's going to overwrite existing file, right? Do you know where it crashes? p.s. why do you want to use a file instead of localStorage? Using file will require you to ask for additional permissions, but localStorage doesn't.

Comment: By local storage, you mean `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.local.createFileAsync("events.txt");` ? Or is there something else to it?

Comment: It's HTML5 feature. `window.localStorage`. Follow these links http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20091029/#the-localstorage-attribute and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466046.aspx